# validation control is always fires

Tags: 2010, validation

I'm try to using validation InputFormRegularExpressionValidator. Code behind

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox runat="server" id="TitleTB"__designer:bind="ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
<SharePoint:InputFormRegularExpressionValidator ID="Validator" runat="server"
                         Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"
                         ControlToValidate="TitleTB"
                         ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]$"
                         ErrorMessage="Enter a valid email address." />
```

Validation is always fired regardless of the input.

Comment: Where is the solve: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/93b93588-d589-4b6e-b328-f15cec9d0b68/#02eb2235-9cfa-47c9-ab85-a1c653349bf6

Comment: Since you found the answer, do you mind if we delete this question?

Comment: i think it question be helpfull to other developers

Comment: Oh, I agree it is helpful. I was just asking because you have it duplicated in two places (here and msdn forums). Would you want to post the answer here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was problem with regex. The right is ^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]$
thank to [Wayne Fan](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/wayne%20fan/)